# How to code 1 week free trial in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am new to chrome extension development. I am trying to add the feature of giving a 1-week free trial to my users and then ask them to pay a monthly subscription.

I want to know what should I code so that my users are able to use my extension for a week and are asked to pay for it. I read the google tutorials regarding the Licensing API but was not able to comprehend it. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have information and sample code [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments).

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Thank you for this link. I was not able to find it. I look into it and try to implement it

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I tried using the link, but it does not tell me in which js file I should put the license retrieval code. Popip.js or the background.js?

Comment: Background script, since you want to check for the payment as soon as the extension is run